# Adding Attachment Display Settings in custom media frame

Tags: php, wordpress

I made my own custom media frame :

```
$('.add').bind('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Create the media frame.
    file_frame = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
        title: 'Select image to insert',
        button: {
            text: 'Insert',
        },
        multiple: true 
    });
    file_frame.open();
});
```

It opens the media manager alright but Attachement display setting part is missing. How can i get that?

Answer (score 0):

Under title, you need to add frame: 'post' and on the callback, you should have frame.on('insert') not frame.on('select')